# Return sub-array from defined range by substrings of defined array elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a sorted array of elements (unique and not consecutive):

```
array= ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]
```

I defined a range of elements:

```
range_1 = ("CC" .. "DD")
range_2 = ("B" .. "E")
```

The range of elements are just strings which refers to an `array` elements but only if `starts_with?` is `true` for these elements. Example:

```
"C", "CC" and "CCC" in range - fits to "CCC" in array
"D", "DD" and "DDD" in range - fits to "DDD" in array
```

The desired results for `range_1` and `range_2` would be like this:

```
result_1 = ["CCC", "DDD"]
result_2 = ["BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]
```

How to implement this in Ruby?

Comment: You know about `start_with?` already. So, where's your code?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I know `start_with?` from here http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F

Comment: I mean, try to solve this yourself. If you were blocked in your previous question, now you should be unblocked (you should have the basic understanding about how those solutions work). We won't always be here to write code for you. :)

Comment: I know how to use `Hash` here (see my self-answer), but I found `Range` more complicated.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
def git_em(array, range)
  array.select {|e| range.any? {|r| e.start_with? r}}
end

array= ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]
range_1 = ("CC" .. "DD")
range_2 = ("B" .. "E")

git_em(array,range_1) # => ["CCC", "DDD"]
git_em(array,range_2) # => ["BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept is the same that of your previous question.

```
array= ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]

range_1 = ("CC" .. "DD")
range_2 = ("B" .. "E")

def subarray(array, range)
  from = range.first
  to = range.last
  idx_from = array.index{ |e| e.start_with?(from) }
  idx_to = array.index{ |e| e.start_with?(to) }
  array[idx_from..idx_to]
end

p subarray(array, range_1)
#=> ["CCC", "DDD"]

p subarray(array, range_2)
#=> ["BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"]
```